# Join two collections of objects

Tags: python, django, join

I have two Models, one that has the name Exam and one that has the name Grades

Exam has primary key **id**. Grades has foreign key **exam_id**.

I want all Exams that have a entry in the Grades table.

This is what I have:

```
grades = Grades.objects.all()
exams = Exam.objects.all().filter(grades__exam__id = id)
```

I get this error:

> TypeError at /exams
>
> id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Can you please help me?

Comment: Do you have any constraints on Exam that enforce the Grades relationships?  If so you can use is not null.  Alternatively I think you are using the built in id() function by accident.  Where are you defining id ?

Comment: Yes, I have constraints on Exam that enforce the Grades relationship. isnull=False returns all records in Exams, despite of any FK relationship with Grades. id should be the field in Exam

Comment: This works:
exams =  Exam.objects.all().filter(grades__id__isnull=False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`id` is a Python built-in](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id).

Answer (score 0):

Your error `id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)` is because you are referencing a variable that is not defined, so it is trying to call the default id built in.

To find all that have a grades FK you can do:

```
exams = Exam.objects.all().filter(grades__exam__id__isnull=False)
```

Comment: This gives me all objects in Exam, not only those who have FK constraints

Comment: This gives you the exams that have a link to grades.

Comment: No it does not. It gives me all the exams, despite of any FK constraint. I have 10 exams, from id 1-10 but only one exam is in the Grades table and exam_id there is 5. So this SHOULD return only that exam, but instead it returns all exams.

Comment: However I tried this:
exams =  Exam.objects.all().filter(grades__id__isnull=False)
and this works

Comment: I can only work with what you give me, and you said your fk was grades__exam__id

Comment: remember to append `.distinct()` to your query.